# How to auto resize blogger image by plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger

```
<div><img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Cte2EwC-9PE/UsbynhiHbtI/AAAAAAAAHRE/jmGB7-eTfoY/s1600/Growing-Food-Plant.jpg" alt="demo image" style="height: 180; width: 150;"></div>
```

Original Image src is `https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Cte2EwC-9PE/UsbynhiHbtI/AAAAAAAAHRE/jmGB7-eTfoY/s1600/Growing-Food-Plant.jpg`

Character to be changed is s1600

My working jQuery

```
$('div img').each(function(n, i){
    var p = $(i);
    var w = $(this).width().toFixed();
    var h = $(this).height().toFixed();
    return p.attr('data-src' , p.attr('data-src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'w' + w + '-h' + h +'-c'));
});
```

The cropped src is `https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Cte2EwC-9PE/UsbynhiHbtI/AAAAAAAAHRE/jmGB7-eTfoY/w150-h180-c/Growing-Food-Plant.jpg`

Changed character is w150-h180-c

The existing jQuery version working perfectly. But not handling more images and bit slow. I tried to convert the jQuery script into plain JavaScript but it is not functioning.

```
var divImage = document.querySelectorAll("div img");
for(var c = 0; c < divImage.length; c++) {
    var wid = divImage[c].clientWidth.toFixed();
    var hei = divImage[c].clientHeight.toFixed();
    var attr = divImage[c].getAttribute("src");
    for(var a = 0; a < attr.length; a++) {
        attr[a].replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'w' + wid + '-h' + hei +'-c');
    }
}
```

Is there anyone who can here to tell me what's wrong with my script?

Advance thanks.

Comment: *"bit slow"* - I think you'll find that it's not the jquery that's slow and converting to the same code but in vanilla javascript will have essentially zero impact.  What makes you think it's your code that's going slowly vs the blogger images being resized dynamically on the server?

Comment: You also might like to try `p.data('src' , p.data('src').replace(/s` which will use the correct `.data()` method rather than `.attr` so should be slightly quicker.   Assuming the blogger framework uses these with `.data` ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what's wrong with my script

Your code is not working because

1. you generate the new url

```
attr[a].replace(...
```

but don't update the attribute on the image

```
divImage[c].setAttribute("data-src", attr[a].replace(...
```

2. you're using

```
divImage[c].getAttribute("src")
```

while your original uses `.attr("data-src")`

3. you're using `.getAttribute()` which returns a string then looping through each letter

```
for(var a = 0; a < attr.length; a++)
```

Giving:

```js
var divImage = document.querySelectorAll("div img");
for (var c = 0; c < divImage.length; c++) {
  var wid = divImage[c].clientWidth.toFixed() || 0;
  var hei = divImage[c].clientHeight.toFixed() || 0;
  var attr = divImage[c].getAttribute("data-src");
  var newattr = attr.replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/, 'w' + wid + '-h' + hei + '-c');
  divImage[c].setAttribute("data-src", newattr);
}

$("div img").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("data-src"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><img data-src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Cte2EwC-9PE/UsbynhiHbtI/AAAAAAAAHRE/jmGB7-eTfoY/s1600/Growing-Food-Plant.jpg" /></div>
<div><img data-src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Cte2EwC-9PE/UsbynhiHbtI/AAAAAAAAHRE/jmGB7-eTfoY/s1600/Growing-Food-Plant.jpg" /></div>
```

Comment: Was missing some `)` - but also noticed `3.` your getting a string then looping each character

Comment: You are brilliant. It is working Perfectly. Thank you very much sir. Thanks again.